# solutions to the annoying "warning: already initialized constant" message

Tags: ruby, constants

Today I've stumbled upon a tricky issue with Ruby constants. In our team someone created a module, which is included into multiple models. In our (spec) test output this results into warning messages such as:

> /home/ayrton/project/lib/life_cycle.rb:5: warning: already initialized
>   constant RESET

One way to solve this is, is to declare your constants like this:

```
module LifeCycle

  unless (const_defined?(:RESET))
    RESET = 'reset'
  end

  #...
end
```

I've also read a blog post, written by Avdi Grimm, which provides an alternative [solution](http://avdi.org/devblog/2011/08/18/do-we-need-constants/), I was wondering what your opinions are, regarding this matter.

Comment: Do you mean it is `require`d in multiple models, or `include`d? It should be loaded only once even if `require`d multiple times

Answer (score 146):

I encountered this same problem today and found a simple solution.

Since the warning is from trying to reassign a constant with its same value, I just changed

```
module LifeCycle
  RESET = 'reset'
end
```

to

```
module LifeCycle
  RESET ||= 'reset'
end
```

This took care of the warning and is a lot simpler than checking if each constant is defined. Let me know if you find a better solution.

Comment: This takes care of the warning very neatly.

Comment: Memoizing is a good solution if the warning is caused by your class being reloaded.  If you're overriding constants from 3rd-party classes it's safer to leave the warning in place.

Comment: This works for Ruby but Rubocop is throwing an error when doing that: `An error occurred while Style/MutableConstant cop was inspecting <file>`

Comment: I forgot about this, but its the perfect solution when you use require_relative

Comment: Keep in mind this doesn't help if the constant is equal to `false` (or `nil`).

Answer (score 26):

This is only a problem in applications that explicitly reload, like Rails applications.

If the verbosity offends you, you can use `unless` as a statement modifier instead:

```
module LifeCycle
  RESET = 'reset' unless const_defined?(:RESET)
end
```

This leaves a few weak arguments against Avdi's suggestion to only use methods:

- constant lookup is faster than method lookup,
- constant values are defined on load, not on (first) request,
- constants visually suggest that they require no work to derive, and

If you like Avdi's suggestion enough to ignore these, go with it.

Comment: This is in fact a Rails application, I was afraid that that the `unless const_defined?` is a solution that masks the problem and not actually solves it.

Comment: If the problem is source reloading, then this masks it. Otherwise, it solves it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

RESET is not a constant if it keeps changing in your code. If you rename it to lower case 'reset', the problem disappears. Ruby thinks Upper case variables are constants and thus displays an error to warn you that a constant has changed.

Comment: I am just running "knife client list". I dunno or modifying any variable

Answer (score 1):

Try `bundle clean --force` and then `bundle update`