# Right way to check if a constant is already defined in a Ruby Class

Tags: ruby, constants, ruby-1.8.7, class-constants

I have certain classes that are implemented as decorators in my Rails app which is on Ruby 1.8.7 . I keep getting the warning - `warning: already initialized constant ABC` . Here ABC is the name of the constant.

To solve this, I'm using the [const_defined?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F) method as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953611/solutions-to-the-annoying-warning-already-initialized-constant-message) .

My doubt is -  is `const_defined?` the right way to check if a class constant is already defined in ruby ? I clearly see that it can be used to check for a module constant.

I was able to see that the `defined?` method can also be used as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171978/check-if-a-constant-is-already-defined). I tried to lookup the documentation of `defined?`, but I don't see a link to its documentation based on my search thus far.

I'm not sure which to choose among the two as I can't see a clear difference between the two at this point.

Could one please suggest which is best to use in this situation and why?.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3398590/477037

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `defined?` is documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000014).

It is better to ask if it is a constant, and use `const_defined?` if it is important that it is a constant.  If you only care that it is defined, then use the keyword `defined?`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 , can you please point me to a documentation specific to this ruby version if exists. Using the const_defined? method within a class shouldn't be a problem? I see that it works but the reason why I'm asking this question is, const_defined? more sounds like something to use with Modules than classes and since it was defined under the ['Module' related documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-const_defined-3F), I had some doubts. Can you kindly confirm? Thanks.

Comment: @boddhisattva, DO NOT use Ruby 1.8.7, it is badly outdated. I mean badly. Use Ruby 2.x, I beg of you.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: Where do these people even *get* ruby 1.8? Every major distro has updated, as far as I know. Even OSX!

Comment: @boddhisattva: modules and classes are basically the same thing. In fact, Class inherits from Module, so every class **is** a module.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I'm completely with you on this :) . But sometimes, when it's not really your decision that counts you have to live with it until you find alternatives.. I completely understand where you're coming from given that the community has stopped supporting this version of Ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Thanks for confirming this and letting me know more about classes in the context of modules.. In my case, Ruby 1.8.7 is already setup, so I'm just using that itself. I understand may be finding a new Ruby 1.8 source would be hard to find :)

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option. This is because Ruby has this pesky `#const_missing` method, that can unexpectedly provide values even there, where `#const_defined?` would indicate *false*:

```
module M
  def self.const_missing sym; 42 end
end

M.const_defined? "A" #=> false
M::A #=> 42
```

For cases like these, you can use `begin ... rescue ... end` statement:

```
begin
  M::A; true
rescue NameError
  false
end
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ruby 1.8.7 it looks your only option is `const_defined?`, as I can't find any documentation from `defined?`

If you we're using Ruby 1.9 I would suggest to use the defined? and check [this document](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) for more information.

Comment: That's because `defined?` is not a method. It is a keyword akin to operators.